# What happens when running out of Cherry Trees in Tokaido: Crossroads?

Tags: tokaido, tokaido-crossroads

In Tokaido, when you play with the Crossroads expansion, you can choose a Panorama or a Cherry Tree card.

What happens when the 6 Cherry Tree cards are gone and someone lands on a pano spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply don't get one.  The rules for crossroads state :-

> When a Traveler stops at a Panorama (Sea, Mountain, or Rice Paddy)
>   space, he must choose between:  • Taking a Panorama card of the
>   corresponding type (basic game rules).  • Taking a Cherry Tree card
>   (if the card is available)

So if a Cherry card is not available you just don't get one and must take the panorama. Of course remembering the basic game rules :-

> Each traveler can create only a single panorama of each type; a
>   traveler who completes a panorama can no longer stop on the spaces
>   corresponding to that type (Sea, Mountain, or Paddy).

To clarify If you have completed the panorama corresponding to that space and the cherry tree cards have all gone you may not choose to land on that space.

Comment: If player completed the corresponding panorama but there is still cherry tree card to choose from, can player stop there?

Comment: I believe there that the expansion rule supersedes the originals.  'when a play stops at a panorama space they may'.  so if they have completed a panorama but the Cherry tree is still available then they may choose to take that option.